# Generating NoSQL database on Google App Engine DataStore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nosql

I would like to create a NoSQL database on Google App Engine using the DataStore, in which I generate the database programmatically: i.e., running a program that downloads XML files and uploads the data as key-value pairs to the DataStore. Is this possible? Are there size restrictions on the database, and would I be able to perform INSERT operations on it from my local computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create entities on local computer and insert them into HRD without the need that the model class of the entity of which you are inserting into HRD even exists on GAE. You just need to have remote api enabled and upload the application on GAE. For more information read here:

- [Remote API for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi)

For Datastore quotas see this document:

- [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore)